install Magento 2.4.7 with a database 2.4.5
We are working with Magento version 2.4.5 and want a clean (new) installation of the latest version 2.4.7 while retaining our current database with 2.4.5, of course.
What is the most sensible sequence:

Install a new (clean) Magento version 2.4.5 with the current database and then migrate to 2.4.7?
or
Install a new (clean) Magento version 2.4.7 and migrate the database to the new environment. (Do I need a special script for that)?


In theory, If you have a database from a lower version, installing a newer version over it and running the db updates should work nicely.
In practice, I've seen this working and not working.
In the cases it didn't work it was because of the custom modules I had that were not compatible with the newer version and threw some errors. In this case you have to solve them one by one or remove the module completely and add it after you make it compatible (which is kind of the same thing as solving the issues one by one).
Before you try to install the the new version over the old db, make sure you have a db backup.
